# Error on ansible playbook: No package matching 'python-pip' found available -on centos guest

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I am trying to install a few packages on centos guest (which was spun through vagrant) through Ansible playbook. This is the snippet where I try to install

```
- name: Installing helpful tools and packages
   yum:
    pkg: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - ntp
    - tcpdump
    - policycoreutils-python
    - vim
    - vim-X11
    - yum-utils
    - deltarpm
    - git
    - ntp
    - python-pip
    - pip
  when:
    - ansible_os_family == "RedHat"

- name: Install shade using pip.
  #become: yes
  pip:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - pip
    - shade
```

This is the error I receive. It's failing to get 'python-pip'

```
TASK [prep : Installing helpful tools and packages] 
****************************
failed: [default] (item=[u'ntp', u'tcpdump', u'policycoreutils-python',  
u'vim', u'vim-X11', u'yum-utils', u'deltarpm', u'git', u'ntp', 
u'python-devel', u'python-pip', u'pip']) => {"changed": false, 
"failed": true, "item": ["ntp", "tcpdump", "policycoreutils-python", 
"vim", "vim-X11", "yum-utils", "deltarpm", "git", "ntp", "python-
devel", "python-pip", "pip"], "msg": "No package matching 'python-pip' 
found available, installed or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["yum-
utils-1.1.31-42.el7.noarch providing yum-utils is already installed", 
"deltarpm-3.6-3.el7.x86_64 providing deltarpm is already installed", 
"No package matching 'python-pip' found available, installed or 
updated"]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe everything on your list is available from the default RHEL/CentOS repo except for python-pip, which I think you have to get from EPEL. Do you have the EPEL repo configured and enabled on the remote system?